# Dialog button breaks my website

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a button the opens a dialog box (the first dialog in the code below).  I works fine.  I've tried to another button (second dialog code below) but it breaks my my website. I'm not a strong coder and if anyone could tell me what im doing incorrectly, id really appreciate it.

```
$( "#dialog-new" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        fluid: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Clear Form": function() {
      clearForm($("#newapsform"));

    },
            "Create Request": function() {

                if(formIsOkay($("#newapsform")))
                {
                    $.ajax
                    ({  
                      type: "POST",  
                      url: "system/aps2.newrequest.php",  
                      data: $("#newapsform").serialize(),  
                      success: function() 
                        {  
                            $( "#dialog-new" ).dialog( "close" );
                            $("#goodmsg").html("Created photo request successfully!");
                            $('#goodmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);

                            datatables.fnDraw();
                            searchtables.fnDraw();
                            phototables.fnDraw();
                            clearForm($("#newapsform"));
                        },
          error: function() 
                        {  
                            $( "#dialog-new" ).dialog( "close" );
                            $("#badmsg").html("Could not create request: Use the force next time.");
                            $('#badmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

$( "#dialog-stat" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  fluid: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "Clear Form": function() {
      clearForm($("#statform"));

    },
    "Create Request": function() {

      if(formIsOkay($("#statform")))
      {
        $.ajax
        ({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "system/aps2.newrequeststatic.php",  
          data: $("#statform").serialize(),  
          success: function() 
          {  
            $( "#dialog-stat" ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#goodmsg").html("Created photo request successfully!");
            $('#goodmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);

            datatables.fnDraw();
            searchtables.fnDraw();
            phototables.fnDraw();
            clearForm($("#statform"));
          },
          error: function() 
          {  
            $( "#dialog-stat" ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#badmsg").html("Could not create request: Use the force next time.");
            $('#badmsgdiv').fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);
          }

        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here are the buttons and below is the actual HTML.

```
$("#newrqbtn").button({
  icons: {primary:'ui-icon-circle-plus',secondary:''}
    }).click(function(e) {
  $("#dialog-new").dialog("open");
});

$("#newrqbtnstat").button({
  icons: {primary:'ui-icon-circle-plus',secondary:''}
}).click(function(e) {
  $("#dialog-stat").dialog("open");
});
```

Here is the HTML side.

```
<button type="button" id="newrqbtnstat" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">New Static Request</button>
```

Comment: Ok, where is the button that opens the dialog? why does it break your website? what do you mean by it breaks your website? what errors are occuring? where within your code does the error occur?

Comment: I added the HTML and buttons.  Also, by "breaks the site", the page just shows up white.  The website loads all the dialog pages when the site loads and then the buttons open up the dialog boxes (at least thats my understanding.)